# How to look back previous rows in spotfire and get a specific value from selected previous row

Tags: formula, spotfire

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11gab.png)

New to spotfire ..
Can anyone tell me what is formula to look back for certain event previous rows and add a cell value from that row..

I tried over function but not fully succeeded.
Any tips ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.